# Third person plural for "pleuvoir"?

Tags: verbes, verbes-défectifs

Apparently the verb *pleuvoir* can only be conjugated in the third person, but I don't understand why you would ever conjugate it in the plural. If *Il pleut* means *It's raining*, what does *Ils pleuvent* mean?

Comment: Dat's called a defective verb, by the way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use this form in a figurative way, when describing objects falling down or being thrown in big quantities. It can also be found in sport comments, usually tennis and maybe boxing, for example *Les coups droits pleuvaient sur le Central* (litterally *Forehands were raining on the Central Court*).

Comment: Hey...your highest rated answer is my highest rated question. This is destiny calling.

Comment: @Aerovistae :-D

Comment: No longer true. Guess destiny hung up before we could answer.

Answer (score 8):

More accurately (IMO) *coups* is a common word for this, but many other terms expressing something abstract can also be used: *insultes* or *injures* is a common exemple in dictionaries too. The [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pleuvoir) has a bunch of examples if you care to look at it.

Comment: +1 for the TLFi reference.

Comment: What is TLFi? I checked out the link but didn't see that acronym anywhere.

Comment: The [*Trésor de la Langue Française*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9sor_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) ("TLF") informatisée ("i").

Answer (score 1):

Strangely several grammar books mention only the impersonal form of pleuvoir and not its figurative form (with ils).

On the contrary, webpages with conjugation usually give both of the possible conjugations. (e.g. https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/pleuvoir_deuxieme-forme.html)

Le Nouveau Bescherelle: L'art de conjugeur adds as a footnote: Quoique impersonnel, ce verbe s'emploie au pluriel mais dans le sens figuré.

> Les coups de fusil pleuvent.
>
> Les sarcasmes pleuvent sur lui.
>
> Les honneurs pleuvaient sur sa personne.