# Are falloir, pleuvoir and neiger the only verbs with only 3rd person singular conjugations?

Tags: conjugaison, verbes-défectifs

I'm working on improving my French conjugation at the moment. Laura K. Lawless has [a page about impersonal verbs](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/impersonal-verbs.htm) but most of them can be conjugated in all persons. The only ones I know of that are only conjugated in the third person singular (defective verbs) are [*falloir*](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/falloir.php), [*pleuvoir*](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/pleuvoir.php) and [*neiger*](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/neiger.php). Are there others?

How accurate and complete are the links I've found? I often find errors and omissions on la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com but I like the way they present their verb tables.

[Third person plural for "pleuvoir"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/third-person-plural-for-pleuvoir) This question has an answer that says that the third person plural can be used in limited situations. Is it the case that these impersonal verbs *can't* be conjugated in the other persons or that they *aren't* usually, but *could* be? For example, in English the defective verb *must* can't be used as the infinitive **to must* in any situations at all.

Answer (score 4):

Un verbe défectif est un verbe qui n'a pas **toutes ses formes** (personnes, modes, temps).

Les voici (la liste n'est peut-être pas complète):

- **falloir** : 3ème personne du singulier - *il faut*. Forme impersonnelle.
- **pleuvoir**: 3ème personne du singulier et pluriel. Forme impersonnelle ou non: *Il pleut des carottes. Les problèmes pleuvent.*
- **gésir**: présent et imparfait de toutes les personnes: *je gis, je gisais.*
- **paître**: pas de passé, pas de participe passé;
- **bruire**, quérir: infinitif, autres formes inusitées
- **choir**: pas d'imparfait, d'impératif, de subjonctif présent, de participe présent, d'impératif
- **échoir**: 3ème personne du singulier et pluriel, pas d'imparfait, pas d'impératif
- **traire**: pas de passé
- **raire** (bramer, crier): idem
- **saillir** : a deux formes: *il saillit* (*jaillir*), qui a à peu près toutes les formes ([le CNRTL indique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saillir) qu'il n'a pas d'impératif), et *il saille* (*être en saillie, déborder*), qui n'a que les formes de la 3ème personne, sans impératif.
- **accroire**, **ester**, **courre** : infinitifs seuls
- **ravoir**: infinitif et formes inusitées: *je raurai*
- **chaloir**: 3ème personne du singulier du présent - *peu me chaut* -, autres formes inusitées.
- **clore** : pas de passé, pas d'imparfait, pas de 2ème et 3ème personne du pluriel du présent
- **forclore**, **éclore**" : idem
- **braire** : pas de passé
- **attraire** : idem
- **comparoir** : essentiellement infinitif et participe présent- *comparant* -
- **ouïr** : le futur, passé, conditionnel, n'ont que la première personne du singulier.
- **sourdre** : présent et imparfait de la 3ème personne.
- **dissoudre** : pas de passé
- **distraire** : idem
- **seoir** : seulement présent, futur, imparfait, subjonctif de la 3ème personne, infinitif et participe présent
- **férir** : essentiellement infinitif - *sans coup férir* -, et passé - *féru* -, autres formes inusitées.

**Le cas de neiger (le seul du premier groupe) est ambigu**. Selon, les sources, on le trouve souvent [limité à la 3ème personne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/neiger), ou [à toutes les personnes](http://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/conjugaison-verbe/neiger.html).

On trouvera également [ici](http://www.aidenet.eu/conjugaison01a.htm) une liste, avec quelques verbes désuets mais dont certaines formes demeurent (tistre, contondre).

Comment: Tu es sûr pour "neiger" ? Pour moi c'est comme "pleuvoir", seulement à la troisième personne... aurais-tu un contre-exemple ?
Pour moi, on peut rajouter à ta liste les verbes qui parlent de la météo comme "neiger" justement ou "grêler"...

Comment: Des références seraient appréciées ;)

Comment: Nous pouvons également ajouter le verbe saillir à la liste, qui ne s’emploie qu'à la troisième personne. Et traire et raire qui n'ont pas de passé simple ni d'imparfait du subjonctif.

Comment: @Jennifer merci. traire était déjà dans la liste, raire ajouté. saillir aussi (plus compliqué car double forme).

Comment: @Pwassonne , ambiguité sur neiger. Souvent limité à la 3ème personne, mais on trouve aussi neigeons ...

Comment: @Pwassonne On peut difficilement appeler des verbes régulier en -er défectif. Même si l'emploi aux autres personnes est rare, on peut à tout moment faire appel à sa connaissance de la morphosyntaxe pour produire les autres formes. "T'aurais pu te secouer avant d'entrer, tu neiges dans tout le hall maintenant !" me semble parfaitement acceptable, et googler un peu permet de dénicher des usages poétiques de pleuvoir à la 1SG : "Je pleus comme novembre, enlisé dans sa brume, froidure que je fume, n'arrêtant pas d'attendre août et quand et comment"

Comment: Bon bah je crois que grâce à ton exemple j'ai enfin compris ce qu'était la morphosyntaxe... xD  je ne sais pas si la définition des verbes défectifs inclut les formes uniquement poétiques ou pas, "tu neiges" me semble de l'ordre du poétique en tout cas (pour moi c'est suffisamment inhabituel pour être "mignon" ^^), mais du coup pour savoir s'il est vraiment défectif ou pas je te fais confiance ^^